# Adding action to custom uiview

Tags: ios, action, custom-view

I have been trying to do this simple thing : adding an action to a simple custom view. I have looked over the internet and found two "easy" solution :

- `UITapGestureRecognizer`
- `UIButton`

I want to do this programmatically and I just need to handle the tap.

Here is my code so far, I've tried both solutions separately and together and it doesn't work !

.m

```
#import "AreaView.h"
@implementation AreaView
#define GREY 27.0/255.0
#define PINK_R 252.0/255.0
#define PINK_G 47.0/255.0
#define PINK_B 99.0/255.0

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName areaName:(NSString *)areaName minimumSpending:(int)minimumSpending andCapacity:(int)capacity
{
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:GREY green:GREY blue:GREY alpha:1];
        self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        //Init variables
        _areaName=areaName;
        _capacity=capacity;
        _minimumSpending=minimumSpending;

        //Image view
        _logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 4, 66, 50)];
        //_logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        _logoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        //Label
        _areaNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 54, 76, 18)];
        _areaNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _areaNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _areaNameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        _areaNameLabel.text = areaName;

        //button
        _button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _button.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        _button.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
        [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //tap gesture racognizer
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

        [self addSubview:_logoImageView];
        [self addSubview:_areaNameLabel];
        [self addSubview:_button];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)handleTap:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"tapped!");
}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"tapped!");
}
@end
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AreaView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *logoImageView;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *areaNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *areaName;
@property (nonatomic) int minimumSpending;
@property (nonatomic) int capacity;
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName areaName:(NSString *)areaName minimumSpending:(int)minimumSpending andCapacity:(int)capacity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

The problem is that both handleTap and tapped are never fired even if I comment the button solution or the tap gesture one to test them separately. For the button implementation, I can see it on my interface but clicking on it does nothing.

My UIView is then added programmatically several times (for several views) in a UIScrollview.

**EDIT 2**

The problem is more complicate than that. The custom view is inside a scrollview which is inside another different custom view whose main function is to rewrite hittest, so that touches on this view are held by the scrollview. [(Here is the purpose of all that)](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html).

It seems that as long as hittest is involved, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't work`? Is button action fired?

Comment: As i think this should be worked at least one event.Check your code again.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it's clearer ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate method, which will help you.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
           id touchedView = gestureRecognizer.view;
           if ([touchedView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
           {
                return NO; //It won't invoke gesture method, But it'll fire button method.
            }
           return YES;
    }
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for. I don't want multiple solutions. I have tested two but I need only one to work : Button or Gesture and it doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your `UIButton` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` selectors aren't firing. However another option to handle taps on a view is to simply override the `touchesEnded:withEvent` method:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //handle a tap
}
```

That way, you won't have to create a `UIButton` or a `UITapGestureRecognizer` object at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's more complicate than that as you can see in my second edit.